# sort alphabetically using pointer arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, c-strings

```
void sort(char *arr[])
{
    char temp[50];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(arr[i],arr[i+1])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp,arr[i]);
                strcpy(arr[i],arr[i+1]);
                strcpy(arr[i+1],temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char *arr[] = {"zxe","pzae","cazaae","daanans"};    
    sort(arr);  
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)  
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

I want to use this code to sort the strings alphabetically, but this does not seem to work. I want to use pointers specifically for this task. Any leads?

Comment: If you step through this line by line you'll see that there's *no way* this was going to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Why copy whole strings around when you could just swap pointers?

Comment: Couldn't you use `qsort`?

Comment: Your indexes are using i and i+1. Your second for loop is for j. shouldn't one of your indexes for comparing/swapping be j?

Comment: What kind of sort are you trying to perform? I do not recognize it.

Comment: My guess on the for loop on j is that it should start at i+1.

Comment: @hibaza Why do you want to use this bad code to sort an array?:)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to swap the pointers, and just iterate from 0 to 2, because you are comparing with the next value `i+1`

```
void sort(char *arr[])
{
    char * temp;
    for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
        {
            if(strncmp(arr[i],arr[i+1],50)>0)
            {
                temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Working code](http://ideone.com/5NT8O2)

Note: 
I used `strncmp` because it is more safe, you can specify `n`: Maximum number of characters to compare.

Comment: Your working code  does not show sorted output. You need 2 for loops. I like the pointer swap instead of strcpy. there is no reason for the arbitrary size of 50 after you changed temp from char[50] to char *.

Comment: You do know this is their homework assignment.  Sometimes it is better to give hints and let them figure it out on their own. Otherwise they could use c++ sort or c qsort.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me

```
void sort(string* arr[])
{
    string* temp;
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            char word1 = (*arr[i]).at(0);
            char word2 = (*arr[j]).at(0);

            if (strncmp(&word1, &word2, 50) > 0)
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    string arr1[] = { "zxe", "pzae","cazaae","daanans" };
    string* arr[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = &arr1[i];
    }
    sort(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << *arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please try and explain your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Smaller inner loop than before. A argument for the size of the array.

```
 void sort(char *arr[], int size)
{
    char * temp;
    for(int j=0; j<size-1;j++)
    {
        for(int i=j+1; i<size; i++)
        { 
            if(strcmp(arr[i],arr[j])>0)
            {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
char *arr[]={"zxe","pzae","cazaae","daanans"};  
sort(arr, size);  
for(int i=0; i<4;i++)   
{
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters this declaration

```
char *arr[] = {"zxe","pzae","cazaae","daanans"};
```

declares an array of pointers to first characters of string literals. In C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays so a correct declaration of the array should look like

```
const char * arr[] = { "zxe", "pzae", "cazaae", "daanans" };
```

To sort the array means to rearrange the elements of the array that is the pointers. The string literals themselves will be unchanged. All you need is to swap pointers to string literals not the string literals. Moreover string literals are immutable. So in any case you may not do what you are trying to do in the program shown in your question. You could do that if instead of the array of pointers to string literals you used a two dimensional array of strings. That is if the array would be declared for example like

```
char arr[][8] = { "zxe", "pzae", "cazaae", "daanans" };
```

You could use standard C++ algorithm `std::sort`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const char * arr[] = { "zxe", "pzae", "cazaae", "daanans" };

    for ( const char *s : arr ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ), 
               []( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
               {
                    return std::strcmp( s1, s2 ) < 0;
               } );

    for ( const char *s : arr ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
zxe pzae cazaae daanans 
cazaae daanans pzae zxe
```

If you want to use the bubble sort method to sort the array then the program can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>

void bubble_sort( const char * arr[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t last; not ( n < 2 ); n = last )
    {
        for ( size_t i = last = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( std::strcmp( arr[i], arr[i - 1] ) < 0 )
            {
                std::swap( arr[i], arr[i - 1] );
                last = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const char * arr[] = { "zxe", "pzae", "cazaae", "daanans" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    for ( const char *s : arr ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    bubble_sort( arr, N );

    for ( const char *s : arr ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as it is shown above that is

```
zxe pzae cazaae daanans 
cazaae daanans pzae zxe
```